# Question about basic property of ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I read the book Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Joseph Gallian. In Page 266, theorem 15.1, the third property claims

If A is ideal and Φ is onto S, then Φ(Α) is ideal.

Where Φ is a ring homomorphism from a ring R to a ring S, A is a subring of R and B is an ideal of S.

My question is if Φ is onto, it will trivially hit every element of S. So Φ(A) is actually S, S is trivially ideal since S is a ring and closed under operation.
There is no answer in the textbook. Did I make any mistakes in understanding this claim? I think it is wrong since it's a bit weird.

Comment: The domain of $\Phi$ likely wasn't $A$.  $A$ was a subring/ideal of the domain.  This is why it's a good idea to write $\Phi: R \to S$ instead of just $\Phi$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Randall commented, $A$ is not necessarily a ring or subring. Even if it were, the image being a subring would not necessarily make it an ideal. Subrings and ideals are very different.

> Claim: If $A\subset R$ is an ideal and $\Phi\colon R\to S$ is surjective, then $\Phi(A)\subset S$ is an ideal.

Proof: clearly $\Phi(A)$ is an abelian group. If $y\in\Phi(A)$ and $s\in S$, then we can write $y=\Phi(x)$ and $s=\Phi(r)$ for some $x,r\in R$. Then $sy=\Phi(r)\Phi(x)=\Phi(rx)\in\Phi(A)$, so $\Phi(A)$ is a left ideal.

> Claim: if $\Phi$ is not surjective, then $\Phi(A)$ need not be an ideal.

Example: take the inclusion $\Phi\colon \Bbb Z\to \Bbb Q$ and the ideal $\Bbb Z$. Note that $\Bbb Z$ is a ring, and $\Phi(Z)$ is a subring of $\Bbb Q$, but not an ideal.

Comment: Sorry I read the book just for self study so I didn't have very solid understanding of ring homomorphism. I understood your first claim but in your second claim you leave me the conclusion without proving. In your second claim, the map you give can be specified by the image of 1. Hence,  subring and non ideal property could be shown by the basic definition, is that right?

Comment: The second example is unclear.  The same point is made just by taking the image of $\mathbb{Z}$ itself.

Comment: You’re right. I started to write something else at first.